# How can I create a Minecraft Pocket Edition server using a domain?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-server

I have bought a domain and I'm not using it.
Is there any way that I could be able to create a running minecraft pocket edition server on this domain website?

I have access to it's FTP.

Comment: so you've bought a server, not a domain. Can you only access the FTP ?

Comment: No. I have a domain that I have a FTP access to it

Comment: domain = "example.com". A server is something you can put files (and execute things) on it

Comment: If you bought a server/domain/whatever for making a *website*, then **no** you will not be able to make a MCPE server. Website servers are completely different from Minecraft servers.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can only access your **server** via FTP (using the **domain name**), you can't execute any app.

If you can use SSH to access the server, I think you can use [PocketMine](http://www.pocketmine.net/).
I havn't tested it, so here's a tutorial : http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2014/06/how-to-create-a-minecraft-pe-server/

Answer (score -1):

Short answer: No.

Long answer:

No. This is not possible. While server software like PocketMine uses PHP it needs to be run by node.js
Hence even though your domain might have PHP templates it would not work.